# Why is the content box expanding when I put anything in it and can I make it not expand/be at a fixed width/height?

Tags: html, css, image, web

I am making a website and at one part I made a flexbox row of 3 boxes, and whenever I put anything in any of the boxes their size expands and pushes away everything else. How do I make it not change it's size regardless of what I put in it? Here is the code:

```css
/*---------CENTER----------*/

div.center-grid {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    
}

#grid1 {
    background-color:red;
    padding-left:250px;
    padding-right:250px;
    margin:20px;
    padding-bottom:650px;
}

#grid2 {
    background-color:green;
    padding-left:250px;
    padding-right:250px;
    margin:20px;
    padding-bottom:650px;
    position:static;
    max-width:0px;
    max-height:0px;
}

#grid3 {
    background-color:blue;
    padding-left:250px;
    padding-right:250px;
    margin:20px;
    padding-bottom:650px;
}

#ingrid1 {
    display:grid;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="center-grid">
            <div id="grid1">
                grid1
            </div>
            <div id="grid2">
                <div id="ingrid1">
                    <image src="content/images/q1.png"></image>
                    <image src="content/images/q2.png"></image>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="grid3">
                grid3
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using max-width in css. Max-width specifies the maximum width of the specified element.

Comment: Well setting the object width and height to 0 kind of helped, thank you